# Avast! crashing my Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, avast

I have got this problem at the past week: All of sudden my Firefox window freezes, I can see some website elements not loading (images etc), and then when I close Firefox (after minute of struggling), and try to start it again, it gives weird error messages like: "not enough resources" or "not valid Win32 program" or "application failed to initialize" or something. I can't launch any program after that, not even CTRL+ALT+DEL, but if I open the taskmanager beforehand, it stays open correctly, so it only fails to start new programs. I am pretty sure this is because of Avast! Also, my Windows windowses start to lose their icons and those error message pop-ups get really wide even though text isn't that wide, and the title isn't always visible, or the text.

Furthermore, I have noticed that every day (at past week) I start my computer, I get this Avast! window requiring me to finish the upgrade, I click OK every time but next day it comes back, even if I didnt upgrade anything. Maybe because I didn't click "install google chrome" ? Is that yet another dirty trick trying to force people to generate money for them?

Anyone had similar problems? I have latest Avast! currently (updated again today), and latest Firefox. I have got Windows XP SP3 (which does not have newest updates, around half a year old updates).

Comment: If you think the problem is avast! try uninstalling it and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: @PeterMaxwell, what would you recommend for replacement?

Comment: @Rookie - at this stage it doesn't matter - you just want to get a working system again. Once you have that you can find and install a different antivirus

Comment: @ChrisF, but how do i test the stability without the internet connection? I cant use internet without antivirus. this error comes randomly after some time of surfing on the web (safe sites though).

Comment: @Rookie - you decide on a different AV product - any will do, uninstall Avast, install the alternate and then carry on.

Comment: Windows security essentials. It works like a charm, never had any problems, never had any viruses.

Answer (score 3):

Before uninstalling your virus scanner do a boot time scan. This will inspect your hard drive before Windows even boots. This will prevent stealthy viruses from gaining control of your virus scanner. After doing a boot time scan uninstall Avast and Firefox, reboot and reinstall.

Comment: Hard drive, that means my Windows partition? Since i got 4 hard drives with total 10 partitions (around 2-4 each), i hope i dont need to scan all of those...

Comment: Start with the partition that your Avast and Firefox are on. After running the boot time scan on that partition, log into windows, uninstall Avast and Firefox, reinstall both programs and then reboot windows. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: So far the Firefox/Windows hasnt crashed, i think the Avast! latest update fixed it, hopefully. Will do reinstall if it still appears...

Comment: Might have had something to do with the Avast WebRep plugin. I disable this. If I wanted the security rating of links before I clicked on them I'd install the WOT (web of trust) software that it looks like WebRep is based on. http://www.mywot.com/en/download

Comment: I think i had disabled it already. Couldnt find that setting now, though...